# Linking to an open ticket pertaining to the problem question is about is wrong?

Tags: support, comments, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, convert-to-comment

I don't get it, [a guy was pointing out some problem in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177364/), I've filled a ticket for the exact same problem and got it accepted.

So why was my answer linking to the ticket deleted/converted to a comment? I got

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their
>   post.

I was saying "you problem has been recognized and is fixed in next version". How is that not an anwser?

Comment: I'm getting moderator bashed :( The linked ticket was only resolved *after* I've anwsered

Comment: Also according to the "duplicate" my answer was still valid, so how do I get it undeleted?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to disagree. ATM, it is "*This has been accepted as improvement https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13741*". If you said it was resolved in issue/version whatever, see bug-report [here] for details, that would be good. Also, would providing a work-around for older versions would be useful...? I edited to clarify, and flagged for a mod to undelete it.

Comment: This ticket has been resolved within hours of me posting the anwser.
So I still don't get it -- is it OK to file tickets in response to SO questions and post them as anwsers once they are *accepted*?

Comment: The point is that just posting the ticket is just a comment, not an answer. Saying that it is fixed in $version is an answer, and benefits from a link to the bug-report. Depending on how likely someone cannot upgrade, the answer might not be very useful without workaround though. Now that I've edited, it is definitely an answer, but I do not know whether adding a workaround would be a good idea.

Comment: Informing that the problem has been recognized and is being triaged still looks like a valid anwser to me.
Still can we then get *this* question unblocked, since it's obviously not a duplicate of the question about resolved tickets

Comment: It's great that you filed a ticket and linked to it in the context of the question, but at the time I saw your answer I applied the standard "would this make sense if the link were broken" test (you'd be surprised how many projects change issue trackers from time to time). In this instance the answer as written would have said no more than "someone is aware, Google it" if the link stops working. Helpful as a comment, but not freestanding. Patches, workarounds, analysis and specific versions that upgrading to would solve the problem make for an answer.

Comment: "you'd be surprised how many projects change issue trackers from time to time" - you mean like the recent codehaus thing? :)

Comment: @Flexo - the question was actually "but i wonder if there is another way to do?". So the workaround and analysis were already included in the answer. I think in this context the answer "you can wait for a fix from original authors" is a valid response.

Comment: Outside of programming if I asked someone for cooking advice, looking for a better way to cook a dish, would "Martha Stewart agreed this is an issue" be a helpful answer or an interesting comment to someone actually in the kitchen?

Comment: Spring developers are more like Bosch than Martha Stewart. Also the guy had already the dish ready, he was asking how he can do better next time.